# django elasticbeanstalk deployment issue with YML config

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

For testing purpose I am trying to upload a django project
in AWS elastic beanstalk. But environment create command `eb create my-env` gives me this error :

```
ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - The configuration file .ebextensions/django.config in application version app-8036-200522_133554 contains invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: while scanning for the next token
found character         '\t' that cannot start any token
 in "<reader>", line 2, column 1:
        aws:elasticbeanstalk:container: ... 
    ^
, JSON exception: Invalid JSON: Unexpected character (o) at position 0.. Update the configuration file.
```

Here is my folder structure.

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── .ebextensions
│   └── django.config
├── .elasticbeanstalk
│   └── config.yml
├── .gitignore
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
└── TaxKH_API
    ├── asgi.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

and here is my .ebextensions/django.config
I have validated the YML using online tool. There is no problem regarding
YML formatting and validation.

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: TaxAPI/wsgi.py
```

Here is a screenshot of that I am not using any type of tab in my file
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyF27.png)

Comment: it seems that, in your django.config you have some `tab` to indent the lines. You should use spaces instead of tabs

Comment: no there is no extra character and I used space everywhere instead of tab

Comment: the error says that you have \t before `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container`. Maybe some strange invisible character has been copied from the browser. Did you try to rewrite the file manually?

Comment: I have edited the post and paste a screenshot. You can see there is no \t anywhere

Comment: yes I tried to rewrite the file manually

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the below steps:

1. Remove any tabs in django.config and use spaces only (2 spaces for indentation)
2. You have to add and commit your changes to your local repo before running `eb` command like `eb create` or `eb deploy` to reflect the changes. `eb` CLI reads only the files from your repo.

Answer (score 0):

option_settings:

XXaws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:

XXXXWSGIPath:Xmyproject.wsgi:application

I was facing a similar problem, I hand typed the django.config file and each X is a single space. So added 2 spaces in 2nd line and 4 spaces in 3rd line followed by another space after WSGIPath.
and then ran the below 2 commands :

1. eb init
2. eb create
   and it worked for me !!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).